# Git (msysgit) clone on Windows giving error

Tags: git

Trying to git clone for the first time using msysgit on Windows and getting this error.

```
fatal: read error: early EOF
fatal: read error: Invalid argument
fatal: recursion detected in die handler

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)
```

Setup:

- git init on my server using

  ```
  git init --bare
  ```
- git deamon to service

  ```
  git daemon --verbose --export-all --enable=upload-pack --enable=receive-pack --base-path=<my_path>
  ```
- and finally

  ```
  git clone git://<ip_address>/reponame
  ```

which gives the error above.

Comment: Is this with any repo?

Comment: With a repo I've set up.

Comment: [Googleing](https://www.google.com/search?q=msysgit+"early+EOF") reveals you're not the first one to hit this problem. I would investigate what people before you faced and possible workarounds they found.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error cloning :

`git clone git@domain.tld:user/repository.git`

to solve it i just change protocol :

`git clone https://user@domaine.tld/user/repository.git`

check it out into your git server like github, bitbucket, etc to get the right URL, if you got the same error doing git pull that will work too.

Answer (score 1):

Your clone command looks wrong to me. You should add the name of your repo.

```
git clone git://<ip_address>/reponame
```

If that doesn't work there are [many alternatives ways of self hosting](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server).

Comment: Sorry about that, just forgot to add the repo in the command above. I'll have a look at alternatives for self hosting, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a networking/connection problem.

1. Try again
2. Try cloning using a url with a different [transport protocol](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols) (ssh://, http://, git://)

Comment: I've tried multiple times. I'm very new to this, sorry. How would I set up a url with a different transport protocol please?

Comment: if you run `git remote -v` it will show you the list of remotes. if you want to change one of them(to use a different protocol) use `git rename <old> <new>`.

Comment: If you use a hosting site like github (for public repos) or bitbucket (for private repos) the remote url will be prominently displayed (https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5749983/git%20remote%20url.PNG) together with buttons for displaying different protocols. You can then use `git remote set-url origin xxx://new.url.here` to change the url. If you have set up the remote repo locally, perhaps as a file share, please consider using a hosting service instead, they are usually a much better option.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm doing it locally. I've added how I set it up above, maybe that will provide more information. Thanks for your help.